# QML: how to anchor taking care of existing margins

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Qt 5.10.1 under Windows 7. I'm trying to anchor some Components inside an Item with margins defined. I mean, I want to anchor taking in account for margins.

My code:

```
Item {
  width: parent.width
  anchors.margins: 100

  Rectangle {
    width: 50
    height: 50
    anchors.right: parent.right
  }
}
```

I would expect the Rectangle will be positioned on the right side but 100 px from the edge. Instead it's placed just to the edge.

Of course I can add:

```
anchors.rightMargin: 100
```

but I have to do this manually for each children of the main Item. I wonder if there's a way to anchor taking care of existing margins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well, your problem is not the position of the `Rectangle` but the position of the parent `Item`.

Since you define the `width` of the Item instead of using explicit anchors, the margins has no effect.

Try to position the Item using anchors instead of width:

```
Item {
  anchors.fill: parent
  anchors.margins: 100

  Rectangle {
    width: 50
    height: 50
    anchors.right: parent.right
  }
}
```

The `Item` will be correctly positionned 100px from its parent and the `Rectangle` will be positionned at the edge of the `Item`.

Note that there is no "CSS padding - like" behavior in QML: you have to explicitely define in each child component how it fills the parent.

---

**Edit (following your comment):**

If using inside a `Row` or `Column`, as far as I know the only solution is to specify a `rightMargin` in every child.

About **padding**:

Padding does not exist in QML (except for  [Qt Quick Controls 2 components](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#padding-prop)): declaring an item as a child of another item does not mean that it is visually located inside its parent. Thus the only way to position an element is by using `anchors` on every child.

If you want to simulate a padding in the parent item you can define it as a `property` and use it in every child:

```
Item {
  readonly property int padding: 100

  width: parent.width
  height: parent.height

  Rectangle {
    width: 50
    height: 50
    anchors {
      right: parent.right
      margins: parent.padding
    }
  }
}
```

Or wrap the children in another `Item`:

```
Item {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin: 100

        Rectangle {
            width: 50
            height: 50
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use `anchors.fill: parent` because it won't be compatible with a `Column` or `Row` for example.

Comment: Well, I was looking exactly for something like the CSS padding behavior...

Comment: I can't think of any other solution than defining the `rightMargin` in every child then... See my update for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Yes, your hint about the "padding" property is the workaround I was talking about when I said "do this manually for each children". Unfortunately I have to do so. Thanks for your explanation, I usually spend hours trying something I can't do...

Comment: I actually think of a third solution: use an empty child Item just for the padding: `Item {id: rightPadding; anchors.right: parent; anchors.margins: 100 }` and then anchor all siblings with `anchors.right: rightPadding.left`. Just another possible "hack" to simulate a padding :-)

Comment: padding does exist in QQC2 though